# getting the error 'Unterminated string literal error' in python script, why?

Tags: python

i have a script that fails basically straight away, getting the error here:

`values.append(f"'{string(value).replace('"', '""')}'")`

with the message 'SyntaxError: unterminated string literal'

But why??

Comment: Provide some test data.

Comment: Can possibly be simplified to: `values.append(str(value).replace('"', '""'))`, as it appears the f-string is superfluous.  Then again, the question in its original (current) state is not reproducible.

Comment: @LoukasPap It's a syntax error. The value of `value` is irrelevant.

Comment: You could use triple quotes (assuming `string` should be `str`): `values.append(f"""'{str(value).replace('"', '""')}'""")`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you cannot nest quotes inside an f-string, even inside a replacement field. The `"` in the first argument to `replace` is terminating the f-string literal, meaning the `"` that you *want* to terminate the string is actually starting a new string literal.

For now, use `f"""..."""` to define the literal.

---

This restriction has been lifted as of (at least) Python
3.12.0.b1 , due to the formalization of f-string literals in the grammar by [PEP 701](https://peps.python.org/pep-0701/):

```
Python 3.12.0b1 (main, Jun  4 2023, 16:00:02) [Clang 11.1.0 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> string = str
>>> value = 9
>>> f"'{string(value).replace('"', '""')}'"
"'9'"
```

Python 3.12 just recently entered beta; 3.12.0b2 is currently available. The final release is expected in October 2023.

Comment: Is there any benefit from doing `string=str` or is it just because the asker has it in the code?

Comment: That was just to prevent the `NameError` the literal would otherwise produce.

Answer (score 1):

Does `values.append(str(value).replace('\"', '\"\"'))`  work?

You may remove *baskclash+double-quote* (`\"`) and just keep *double quote* (`"`) if you want.

Comment: You are currently appending a `set` value to the list.

Comment: Why do I append a `set` value? You mean a `set` sth like `(1,2,..)`? I don't understand.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Do you mean a `dict`?

Comment: Ohh I didn't know that it creates a `set`. I corrected it.